# How can I get icpc to tell me which files it uses for linking?

Tags: icc, verbosity

I'm linking some compiled code with icpc, e.g.:

```
icpc -o my_executable f1.o /path/to/f2.a -lfoo -lbar
```

I want icpc to tell me exactly which files it uses for the linking - which `.a`, `.o` and `.so*` and where. If possible, I want to be able to filter out files it looks at but eventually does not use; but even a superset of the files actually used is good enough.

How can I do that? I tried finding an appropriate command-line option for this and failed.

Note: I'm looking for a solution which doesn't depend on the link *succeeding*...

Answer (score -1):

You can use the **ldd ./executable** to know the files that are used. It will list all the dynamic libraries that are dependent.

Thanks

Comment: 1. Not all files icpc uses may end up actually being useful. 2. Who said the linking succeeded? If it had, I would probably not care all that much...

Comment: Could you please let us know the exact use case and what you are expecting as an output?